# Use xmlhttp data for Google Maps api v3 polyline

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps, google-polyline

I use an xmlhttprequest to get coordinates out of a mysql database. This works with the following code:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://skyline-va.de/phpvms/lib/skins/crystal/mysql.php?id="+this.flightdetails.id,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Looking at the firebug console I see that this outputs the data in this format

```
new google.maps.LatLng(51.2848358165405, 6.77062893232108),
new google.maps.LatLng(51.2848358165405, 6.77062893232108),
new google.maps.LatLng(51.2848358165405, 6.77062893232108),
new google.maps.LatLng(51.2848358165405, 6.77062893232108),
```

and so on.
But how can I use this to display a polyline in Google Maps api? I've already tried searching google, unfortunately I couldn't find anything useful. I've also tried several things without success.

Thanks!

EDIT:
Here is the map I am working on right now:
http://skyline-va.de/phpvms/index.php/acars/viewmapbig
Basically what I want to do is if you click on one of the planes, the flightpath should be displayed as well. I have the coordinates stored in a database but I have to do the query after the plane is clicked.

EDIT2:
I managed to output the data in xml format with the google documentary. But I can't get the code to work supplied by Google to display the data.
I want to add every new point that comes through the for command to an array.

```
 function downloadUrl(url,callback) {
     var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
         new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
         new XMLHttpRequest;

 request.open('GET', url, true);
 request.send(null);
}
 var flightPlanCoordinates = [
 ];
downloadUrl("http://skyline-va.de/phpvms/lib/skins/crystal/output-xml.php?id="+this.flightdetails.id, function(data) {
  var xml = data.responseXML;
  var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

    flightPlanCoordinates.push(new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"))));

  };
});
flightPath2 = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: flightPlanCoordinates,
                strokeColor: "#FF0000", strokeOpacity: 1.0, strokeWeight: 2
            });
            flightPath2.setMap(map);
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You should consider to use a more suitable format(json or xml). Currently the returned data may only be processed via eval

Comment: The php file now outputs xml data but I still have problems displaying the polyline on the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally managed to get everything working now. The solution is this code:

```
var flightPlanCoordinates = [
 ];
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://skyline-va.de/phpvms/lib/skins/crystal/output-xml.php?id="+this.flightdetails.id,false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
 var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  flightPlanCoordinates[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"), markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
}

flightPath2 = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: flightPlanCoordinates,
                strokeColor: "#04B431",
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2
                });
            flightPath2.setMap(map);
```

Thanks to everyone who helped to solve this problem!

Comment: good to hear that!

don't forget to use flightPath.setMap(null); to hide the paths on click!

Comment: Yes I've already done that. The code to hide the both paths is located somewhere else in the script and it is `flightPath2.setMap(null);`.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

from your XHR data, I found the destination and source co-ordinates. I created an object out of it like this:

```
var flightPathCoords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(48.6903, 9.19521),
    new google.maps.LatLng(32.0136, 34.8866),
];
```

and then created a poly object using the following properties

```
var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPathCoords,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#ffff00',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
});
```

and then bound this object to the map using :

```
 flightPath.setMap(map);
```

all you have to do now is to create a method and bind it to onclick of your flight, which would toggle the path or set it to null .

hope this helps.

**EDIT**

You could do something like this:

```
var paths = {};

xhr = function(){
    ....
    var flightData = response.responseText;
    ....
    paths[flightData.flightID] = new Array(flightData.coord1,flightData.coord2);
}

 populateMap = function(){
    ....
    var currentFlight = "ba057"; // get currentflight id
    currentCoords = paths.currentFlight;

    var flightPathCoords = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(currentCoords[0]),
        new google.maps.LatLng(currentCoords[1]),
    ];

    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: flightPathCoords,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#ffff00',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
    });

    flightPath.setMap(map);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that those coordinates are dynamic. There is one entry being added about every 30 seconds and in addition to that every plane has a different id and therefore different database entries.

Comment: I can see that you have managed to put down start/end points in populateMaps method. I suggest that you create a global object, then dynamically populate the object with the parameters you need on XHR request.

Comment: Thanks, I've managed to output the data in xml format and edited my question.

Comment: I probably just don't know how to display that because if I print out the array, it's empty.

Comment: flightPlanCoordinates array? if yes, try moving that out of your function and try again?

Comment: Yes flightPlanCoordinates is the array where all the coordinates from the xml should be stored in order to create the polyline later on. Putting `var flightPlanCoordinates = [];` in front of `function downloadUrl(url,callback) {` didn't work.